# how to display list in tabular format in jsp using jstl

Tags: java, list

I have java code in which I'm retrieving data from database and putting it in list.But when I run the jsp page then the data is dispalyed in random wa.I want to arrange that data in tabular format .How to do that.
MY java code is:

```
public List<String> alarm_Detail()

{

     String []alarm = null;
        try
        {  
          con = getConnection();

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql= "select distinct * from i2alarmlog where Ack_status=0 AND Direction='CAME' ";
        stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rs = stmt.getResultSet();

        while(rs.next()) 
        {

            lt.add(rs.getString("device_name"));

            lt.add(rs.getString("system_name"));

            lt.add(rs.getString("alert_text"));

            lt.add(rs.getString("arrival_time"));

            lt.add(rs.getString("ack_time"));

            lt.add(rs.getString("ack_status"));

        }



        }

        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println("\nException in Display Bean in getDbTable(String code):"+e);
        }
        finally
        {
            closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
        }

        return lt;
}`
```

JSP CODE IS:-

```js
<jsp:useBean id="ab" class="alarm.Alarm_Bean">

</jsp:useBean>
<c:out value="${ab.alarm_Detail()}"></c:out>`
```

Comment: What is the type of lt? How is the result displayed now (i.e. just in a line comma seperated how?) and what are you looking for? Do you need all the fields that you are adding or just specific?

Comment: @almasshaikh lt is a list of string type.The result is displayed in line comma separated . I need two fields namely system_name and arrival_time along with a third column which represents the number of times a particular system_name appears in table.

Comment: @SRY_JAVA how many records your query is returns ? is it more than one ?

Comment: @JavaDev yes its more than 1,around 2400

Comment: than your approach is wrong this way you have around 2400 records in list and how can you find value of `arrival_time` other for all records?

Comment: @JavaDev I will take only arrival_time and sytem_nam ein my list .But I don't know how to put them in tabular format through jsp and jstl.

Comment: @SRY_JAVA see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a bean class that contain all parameter you got as result of the query like below

```
class MyBean 
{
    private String device_name;
    private String system_name;
    private String alert_text;
    private String arrival_time;
    private String ack_time;
    private String ack_status;

    //Getter and Setter method
}
```

Now use this bean class to store your data.
Create new bean object for every records and add this to your list.

```
List<MyBean> lt = new ArrayList<MyBean>(); 
while(rs.next()) 
{
    MyBean obj = new MyBean(); 

    //Set your recodrs using setter method.
    obj.setSystem_name(rs.getString("system_name"));
    obj.setArrival_time(rs.getString("arrival_time"));

    lt.add(obj);
}
//Return your list to JSP side
```

Now use this bean list and iterate it JSP file to create table as show below :

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <!-- rest of you columns -->
   </tr>

   <c:forEach items="${beanListObj}" var="list">
     <tr>
         <td>${list.device_name}</td>
         <td>${list.system_name} - ${list.arrival_time}</td> // you can add values in one column
         <!-- rest of you columns data-->
     </tr>
   </c:forEach>

 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try c:forEach to iterate over your alarm details as below:

```
<%-- Table definition and other view logic goes here -->
<c:forEach var="alarmDetails" items="${alarmDetailsList}"> <%-- assuming you set the list -->
   <tr>
       <td>${alarmDetails["arrivalTime"]}</td>
       <td>${alarmDetails["systemName"]}</td>
   </tr>
<c:forEach>
```

Now define a class called AlarmDetails like below:

```
public class AlarmDetails {
    String systemName;
    String arrivalTime;//change data type as per your field type in DB
    //other fields goes here
    //getter and setter for the same
}
```

Now instead of defining list of Strings, define list of AlarmDetails like below:

```
List<AlarmDetails> alaramDetailsList = new ArrayList<AlarmDetails>();
 AlarmDetails alarmDetails;
 while(rs.next()) 
    {
        alarmDetails = new AlarmDetails();
        alarmDetails.setSystemName(rs.getString("system_name"));
        alarmDetails.setArrivalTime(rs.getString("arrival_time"));
        //other fields
        alarmDetails.add(alarmDetails);
    }
```

Change the return type of this method to :

```
public List<AlarmDetails> alarm_Detail() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use table tag and iterate your list.

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading1</th>
    <th>Heading2</th>
  </tr>

<c:forEach items="${yourList}" var="i">
<tr>
    <td>${i.id}</td>
    <td>${i.name}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>

</table>
```

Comment: These would be the properties of your bean class.

Comment: the code above is my bean class only,I'm not using servlet in it.Do I ahve to write system_name and arrival_time at the place of id and name..??

Comment: You should create a DTO(Data Transfer Object) and populate your DTO with the values you fetched from DB.Then send a list of this DTO to your jsp.